# Serverside solution for converting an SWF file to a VIDEO file

Tags: video, flash

Right now i develop an RIA application, for online movie creating.
Main data format it`s a server side generated swf files.
I need an server side solution for automated swf to video converting.

After some researching and experiments, i found two solutions:

1. Rewrite a bit an open source flash player **gnash**
2. Grab adobe flash player directly through virtual X server

But both methods has a number of disadvantages like this:

1. gnash support only old formats of swf
2. grabbing work real time only

Someone can suggest another way to do this stuff?

Comment: Screen cast of a virtual X server grabbing:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8W6jyjXjmnE

Answer (score 1):

Interesting,

I spotted [this SimpleFLVWriter](http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/simpleflvwriteras-as3-class-to-create-flvs/) made for AIR, but I guess it could be adapted to have the writing to a file on the server. I theory you could load the swf, check the framerate, take a bitmapData snapshot every frame then send all the bitmapDatas as binary(ByteArray) to the server to write it as flv.

Just my 2 pennies.

Comment: This solution useless in most of cases, because of very low performance, low image quality and high internet traffic :(

Comment: hmmm...you're right :( I guess there should be some java based or other type of tool to 'record' the playing swf and write it to an flv. great question btw!